# Clickable routing without link tag in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to navigate to another page when that component is clicked so i used to do that easily with `Link tag` but i want to navigate without link tag . is there any routing concepts rather that this Link tag . can someone clarify me pls .Here i attached my code ,

```js
// Libraries
import React, { Component, Button, PropTypes } from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

import {Row} from './dataTables/Row';

class Customers extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.customersActions.fetchCustomers();
  }

  render() {
    return (
     <div className="customer-container">
       <div className="body-container">
          <div className="row-scroll">

             {this.props.customersData.customers.filter(function(customer, index) {
               if(index != 0) return true;
               else return false;
              }).map(customer =>

          <Link to={'/customer/'+ customer.customer_id} key={customer.customer_id}                        className="line-removal">
            
            <Row customer={customer} />
           
           </Link>   // what are all the other options instead of Link ???

                
              )
             }
             
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return { customersData: state.customers };
}

export default connect(
  })
)(Customers);
```

above is my code , can someone pls help me out from this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `history.push()` and standard react `onClick` to build the same behaviour like `<Link />` provides.

Working demo *(click on "Go to About" button)*: https://codesandbox.io/s/ER23MMvL0

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export default ({ history }) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    history.push('/about');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Go to About</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import About from './About';

const styles = {
  fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
  textAlign: 'center',
};

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <div style={styles}>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <hr/>

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Hearty Thanks for your time hinok , but i want it as a clickable row not as a Button !!! . Still i got Stucked with that issue only .

Comment: It's just a pattern with `stopPropagation()` so you can apply it to `<Row />`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useNavigate()` in Router v6.

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  <button onCLick={() => navigate("/about")}>Click me!</button>;
};
```